# What is the bug JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext about springboot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jetty, embedded-jetty

When I use the command `java -jar mypro-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --logging.level.root=TRACE` ,the springboot failed ,but some computer could works,
the springboot version is 2.0.0.RELEASE,

```
      <group>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
          <exclusions>
              <exclusion>
                  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
              </exclusion>
```

the log as followers:

```
2018-07-07 18:02:27.487 DEBUG 21534 --- [           main] o.e.j.u.DecoratedObjectFactory           : Creating Instance: class org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.encoders.LongEncoder
2018-07-07 18:02:27.487 DEBUG 21534 --- [           main] o.e.j.u.DecoratedObjectFactory           : Creating Instance: class org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.encoders.ShortEncoder
2018-07-07 18:02:27.487 DEBUG 21534 --- [           main] o.e.j.u.DecoratedObjectFactory           : Creating Instance: class org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.encoders.ByteBufferEncoder
2018-07-07 18:02:27.487 DEBUG 21534 --- [           main] o.e.j.u.DecoratedObjectFactory           : Creating Instance: class org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.encoders.ByteArrayEncoder
2018-07-07 18:02:27.487 DEBUG 21534 --- [           main] o.e.j.s.h.AbstractHandler                : starting org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedErrorHandler@7d0b7e3c
2018-07-07 18:02:27.488  INFO 21534 --- [           main] o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler                 : Started o.s.b.w.e.j.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext@4310d43{/,[file:///tmp/jetty-docbase.8016560841686360205.13000/],AVAILABLE}
2018-07-07 18:02:27.488 DEBUG 21534 --- [           main] o.e.j.w.WebAppContext                    : postConfigure o.s.b.w.e.j.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext@4310d43{/,[file:///tmp/jetty-docbase.8016560841686360205.13000/],AVAILABLE} with org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.ServletContextInitializerConfiguration@5824a83d
2018-07-07 18:02:27.488 DEBUG 21534 --- [           main] o.e.j.w.WebAppContext                    : postConfigure o.s.b.w.e.j.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext@4310d43{/,[file:///tmp/jetty-docbase.8016560841686360205.13000/],AVAILABLE} with org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.websocket.servlet.JettyWebSocketServletWebServerCustomizer$1@537f60bf
2018-07-07 18:02:27.488 DEBUG 21534 --- [           main] o.e.j.w.WebAppContext                    : postConfigure o.s.b.w.e.j.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext@4310d43{/,[file:///tmp/jetty-docbase.8016560841686360205.13000/],AVAILABLE} with org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.JettyServletWebServerFactory$1@5677323c
2018-07-07 18:02:27.488 DEBUG 21534 --- [           main] o.e.j.w.WebAppContext                    : postConfigure o.s.b.w.e.j.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext@4310d43{/,[file:///tmp/jetty-docbase.8016560841686360205.13000/],AVAILABLE} with org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.JettyServletWebServerFactory$2@18df8434
2018-07-07 18:02:27.488 DEBUG 21534 --- [           main] o.e.j.s.h.AbstractHandler                : starting org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ErrorHandler@a38c7fe
2018-07-07 18:02:27.489  INFO 21534 --- [           main] o.e.j.s.Server                           : Started @4487ms
2018-07-07 18:02:27.512 DEBUG 21534 --- [           main] o.e.j.s.Server                           : doStop org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@2dc54ad4[9.4.8.v20171121]
2018-07-07 18:02:27.513 DEBUG 21534 --- [           main] o.e.j.s.Server                           : Graceful shutdown org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@2dc54ad4[9.4.8.v20171121] by 
2018-07-07 18:02:27.514 DEBUG 21534 --- [           main] o.e.j.s.h.AbstractHandler                : stopping org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@2dc54ad4[9.4.8.v20171121]
2018-07-07 18:02:27.514  INFO 21534 --- [           main] o.e.j.s.session                          : Stopped scavenging
2018-07-07 18:02:27.514 DEBUG 21534 --- [           main] o.e.j.s.h.AbstractHandler                : stopping org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ErrorHandler@a38c7fe
2018-07-07 18:02:27.514 DEBUG 21534 --- [           main] o.e.j.s.h.AbstractHandler                : stopping o.s.b.w.e.j.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext@4310d43{/,[file:///tmp/jetty-docbase.8016560841686360205.13000/],UNAVAILABLE}
2018-07-07 18:02:27.514 DEBUG 21534 --- [           main] o.e.j.s.h.AbstractHandler                : stopping org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedErrorHandler@7d0b7e3c
2018-07-07 18:02:27.515 DEBUG 21534 --- [           main] o.e.j.s.h.AbstractHandler                : stopping org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler1420232606==dftMaxIdleSec=1800
2018-07-07 18:02:27.515 DEBUG 21534 --- [           main] o.e.j.s.h.AbstractHandler                : stopping org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler@26e356f0
2018-07-07 18:02:27.515 DEBUG 21534 --- [           main] o.e.j.s.h.AbstractHandler                : stopping org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext$JettyEmbeddedServletHandler@4b8ee4de
2018-07-07 18:02:27.517  INFO 21534 --- [           main] o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler                 : Stopped o.s.b.w.e.j.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext@4310d43{/,[file:///tmp/jetty-docbase.8016560841686360205.13000/],UNAVAILABLE}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something called `Server.stop()` which is performing a graceful stop of the server.

The logging line with ...

```
o.e.j.s.Server : doStop org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@2dc54ad4[9.4.8.v20171121]
```

... is telling you this.

You can add a breakpoint within [`Server.doStop()`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.11.v20180605/jetty-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Server.java#L424-L505) (the code that handles the `.stop()` command from the `LifeCycle`) and see where that call came from.